# Correctness of Proof by Refutation

Tags: proof-verification

I am trying to solve the following by proof by refutation:

```
A or B 1.
NOT A or I 2.
NOT B or T 3.
NOT I 4.
NOT T 5.
```

Where the goal is to prove a contradiction.

My approach has been:

```
NOT A 6. [2+4]
NOT B 7. [3+5]
CONTRADICTION 8. [1+6+7]
```

By the logic that:

```
(A OR B) AND NOT A AND NOT B IMPLY CONTRADICTION
```

The book however solves it by deriving:

```
A [1+7]
```

Ie: Using NOT B together with A OR B

And then calling a contradiction by A AND NOT A.

Would my strategy be acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) :

> $\lnot (A \lor B) \Leftrightarrow (\lnot A \land \lnot B)$.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I can simply assume De Morgan's Law without having to justify further correct?

Comment: @DarioP - it depends on the set of rules you are allowed to use ... How you justify step 6 ? You have used : from $P \lor Q$ and $\lnot P$, derive $Q$ (this is [Disjunctive syllogism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism) ).